# Unable to upload standalone watchOS app to TestFlight; only "Custom" option visible

Tags: watchos

I'm encountering an issue while trying to upload a standalone watchOS app to TestFlight.

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Created a new watchOS project in Xcode, specifically selecting the "Watch-only App" option.
2. Archived the watchOS target using "Product" > "Archive."
3. Selected "App Store Connect" as the distribution method and "Upload" as the build type.

However, when prompted to choose the app in App Store Connect, only the "Custom" option is displayed. I'm unable to select my standalone watchOS app.

I've already checked the following:
Platform Selection: Ensured that only "watchOS" is selected as the platform, not "iOS" or both.

Can anyone offer guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully upload the standalone watchOS app to TestFlight?